# Bitwise operation on Ruby string

Tags: ruby, bit-manipulation

In a block of C++ code, I saw something like this:

```
enum {
  a = 0,
  b = (1U << 0),
  c = (1U << 1),
  d = (1U << 2)
}
```

To achieve the same thing in Ruby, would I have to do something like this?

```
d = "1U".bytes.inject { |x,y| (x<<8) | y } << 2
```

Or would I need to do something else to accomplish what the C++ code does?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1U in the C++ is not a string, it is the unsigned number 1. In fact, the code above in C++ could be substituted by:

```
a = 0;
b = 1U;
c = 2U;
d = 4U;
```

In ruby you can simply do

```
> 1 << 0
 => 1 #0001
> 1 << 1
 => 2 #0010
> 1 << 2
 => 4 #0100
```

But you are not using bytewise operations in ruby unless you have a very good reason for it, right? :-)

Comment: Ah okay, thanks! I'm taking some C++ code and converting it into Ruby but that bit (pun not intended) messed me up since I don't really program in C++ and don't see that representation of values.